# Developing Backbone.js Applications textbook: base.css and bg.png

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, github

I am following along a textbook ("Developing Backbone.js Applications" by [Addy Osmani, who runs his own GitHub account](https://github.com/addyosmani)) to build my first Backbone.js app, and it seems that I can't download two of the files that I need for the app, base.css and bg.png, from his repositories. Like, when I even try to type up the repository that has base.css, I am bought to a GitHub themed page indicating a 404 error.

Could you please help me find the files I need for this app?

Comment: Could you post the bad URLs?

Comment: Sure.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/addyosmani/todomvc/gh-pages/assets/base.css
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/addyosmani/todomvc/gh-pages/assets/bg.png

Comment: I don't know what are the files you are looking for, but have you looked at the root of the repo? Maybe you can find what you need. https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages

Comment: Hang on, I'll go check.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's these two (there's definitely more than one file called base.css, but I found two of them where the code could possibly be the same (except I'll need to write a Java program to compare them.):
https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/duel/src/main/webapp/bower_components/todomvc-common/base.css
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tastejs/todomvc/gh-pages/examples/derby/public/components/todomvc-common/bg.png

Comment: If you want to compare two files you can use an online diff tool, like this one: http://www.quickdiff.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79990/discussion-between-gregpdesjav-and-diogodoreto).

Answer (score 1):

You may have come across an older version of the book, as it seems that the links have been fixed now. These links will work:

- [base.css](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/addyosmani/todomvc-backbone-es6/gh-pages/app/bower_components/todomvc-common/base.css)
- [bg.png](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/addyosmani/todomvc-backbone-es6/gh-pages/app/bower_components/todomvc-common/bg.png)

These are common styles from a site called [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/), so any copy of the CSS or bg.png you might have found should work fine.